# Emacs proper indentation for python code after newline ala PyCharm

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

PyCharm will ident the line after a == b correctly after I press enter:

```
if a == b:
   print "something"
```

but when in emacs, it will give me:

```
if a == b:
print something
```

I already have python-mode enabled together with ergoemacs. Can someone who has done this before share how to to it ala PyCharm ?

**Update:**
**alt-return seems to be doing what I want**

Answer (score 2):

C-j does newline-and-indent, which is what you are looking for probably.

With python-mode.el, <kbd>RET</kbd> is bound to `py-newline-and-indent` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Press 'tab' key anywhere on the `print something` line - it should indent properly. This works for most modes.

EDIT
In other modes which **do not have strict indenting rules like python** you can highlight everything and Ctrl+Meta+\ will try to format everything.

Comment: In python, Ctrl+Meta+\ is very dangerous.  Python indentation has meaning, and often is ambiguous.  Ctrl+Meta+\ (indent-region) can modify the logic of your code.

Comment: I really like this particular ability of emacs and I really miss it when going to other editors!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running the "wrong" python mode.

Your distribution most likely ships `python-mode.el`, which I - personally - find to be a bit clumsy.

Instead, try [**`python.el`**](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el). Just download the file, put it into `~/.emacs.d/` and add

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/python.el")
```

to your `~/.emacs` file.

While you're at it, here are some good settings for whitespace and maximum line length:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda ()
 (setq whitespace-line-column 79)
 (setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the costs of refactoring are high with Emacs Lisp, that's why some functions, where speed matters, indeed are monsters at python-mode.el. Try to build the index with some large file, you'll learn the reasons.

Comment: python.el is included in Emacs as of 24.3.  The Github repository is abandoned.